# Call Shopify API from React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

## What I managed to do so far

I followed this guide to setup a Shopify app with a Rails backend + React:
https://medium.com/@esimonian16/setting-up-a-shopify-app-with-rails-5-1-webpack-react-and-polaris-b8535d911275

Everything seems to work fine. I'm using the shopify_app gem.

When I navigate to my app in the merchant dashboard, The home controller in Rails renders a React app that displays some products (these were passed from rails to react as JSON).

---

## What I would like to do now

I want to have a button in React 'List customers', which should then update the react components and show all the customers as a list.

I have created a new controller at `my-app.com/customers`

```
class CustomersController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
    def index
        customers = ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })
        render json: customers
    end
end
```

If I go to `my-app.com/customers` in the browser I get the correct json response.

---

I then tried fetching this data from React.

```
fetch('https://my-app.com/customers', {
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(parsedJSON => {
  console.log(parsedJSON);

  // Update state
  // this.setState(...);
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The Rails backend doesn't allow the request to get this data, because it is not authorized, so it get's redirected to `/login`

In React, I have access to the `session.token`, however I'm not sure how to use it to authenticate my request?

## Questions

1. How do I make such calls to the Shopify API? Am I trying the right approach, i.e use my backend between React and the actual Shopify Api call?
2. How do I authenticate my call so that they pass just as if I'm calling `/customers` in the browser?
3. I guess making Shopify Api calls directly from React would be a really bad idea, because I would expose my secrets to the world, right?
4. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I make calls they are relative to my App, not to some external URL... so in your case... https://my-app.com/customers might be better as just /customers.

Comment: Yup, entering the domain for your app is also dangerous in the react ( frontend ) as it can invite brute attacks
Just try normal /customers instead of the entire url just like @david-lazar explained here